# shifting array to the left by 4 cell

Tags: java, arrays

i wanted to shift a given array by, say 4 cell and fill the shifted place with 0. This is what I did:

```
public class LinearArray{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int [] b = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
        shiftLeft(b,4);
        printArray(b); // This Should Print: { 40, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
    }

    public static void shiftLeft(int [] source, int k){
        for(int i=0,j=i+k;i<source.length-k;i++,j++){
            source[i]=source[j];
            source[j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of getting the output  40, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0
I am getting 50, 60, 30, 40, 0, 0
if i set k=5 instead of 4 i get 60, 20, 30, 40, 50, 0
What am i doing wrong and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` condition is wrong: For example for `k=4` the condition is `i < 2` - the loop body is executed 2 times, each time setting 2 values => your code does not even get a chance to change all array entries.

Your loop logic has to be changed, e.g.:

```
public static void shiftLeft(int [] source, int k){
     int newLength = source.length - k;
     for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        source[i] = i < newLength ? source[i + k] : 0;
    }
}
```

That ensures that the body is executed exactly `source.length` times. Every step one value is changed. The value it is changed to depends on wether or not the current index is smaller than the number of entries that should be non-zero in the end. If it is lower the value is equal to the original value at the index+(number of entries). Otherwise the value is `0`.

Comment: can you explain this part a little bit more?
int newLength = source.length - k;

Comment: @Miraj its only purpose is to make the check in the loop easier. `source.length - k` is the number of array entries you want to preserve: if you want to shift by 2, then you will end up with 6-2=4 entries in the array != 0.

Comment: what if i want to shiftRight by 4cell? what would be the newLength?

Comment: @Miraj 2 since you have 6 elements and 6-4=2